# Representing distances in high-dimensional space

Tags: graph-theory, network

I have a set of n points $P_i$ $(i=1..n)$ in an d-dimensional space. I can calculate the distances of every point to each other point.

> What is the best way to represent the distances of these points?
>
> What is the best way to see whether some of the points group together?

(Primarily i'm searching for the idea how this can be done in general, not specifically for a software implementation.)

**Example:**

Let n=5, d=4:
$$P_1=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, P_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}, P_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\5\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, P_4=\begin{pmatrix}0\\6\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, P_5=\begin{pmatrix}0\\5.5\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

I can simply calculate the distance $\Delta_{i,j}=||P_i - P_j||_2$, and get
$$\Delta^2_{1,2}=1, \Delta^2_{1,3}=25, \Delta^2_{1,4}=36, \Delta^2_{1,5}=31.25,\\ \Delta^2_{2,3}=26, \Delta^2_{2,4}=37, \Delta^2_{2,5}=32.25\\ \Delta^2_{3,4}=1, \Delta^2_{3,5}=1.25,\\ \Delta^2_{4,5}=1.25$$

Here, $P_1$ and $P_2$ as well as $P_3$, $P_4$, $P_5$ are grouped together (their mutual distance is small).

Is there a way to represent this behaviour graphically?

Comment: Are you looking for Software that can represent N-Dimensional space via 2-D/3-D graphics? I have just Googled an old paper on visualising N-dimensional geometry here: http://www.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/~mlanzenberger/teaching/ps/ws07/stuff/00146402.pdf

Comment: Thanks for this paper, going through it now. I'm not searching for a software, but rather the idea itself how this can be done in the best way. will revise the question accordingly. Thx!

Comment: Another comment is that this question may be NP-Complete. There is an NP Complete problem called CLUSTERING which is similar to this. I could say a little bit more, but it wont be an Answer as such.

Comment: Roy, thanks, that hint to CLUSTERING is very interesting. interesting that it is NP hard, however - fast heuristic algorithm exist. I am not 100% sure yet wether I can apply those algorithm. If you have more infos, i would be happy. (oh, and i consider your comment as a very useful answer ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

*Converting Roy's comment into an answer so this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" queue*

---

This question may be NP-Complete. There is an NP-Complete problem called CLUSTERING which is similar to this.